# ¿Importa el orden de los campos cuando se crea un documento en MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy aprendiendo a usar MongoDB y NodeJS.

Al estar trabajando me preguntaba si importa el orden de los campos a la hora de crear/insertar un nuevo documento dentro de una colección.

Les dejo una imagen para que vean a lo que me refiero, en ella se puede observar como al crear un nuevo documento manualmente, los campos se crean con el siguiente orden: id, name, age. Pero a la hora de insertar un nuevo documento utilizando un método post (express, nodejs, formulario) los campos se crean en el siguiente orden: id, age, name.

Las preguntas son: ¿Importa el orden de los campos o es indiferente? Por ejemplo, se me ocurre querer realizar una iteración (o alguna otra operación), eso resultaría en un problema ¿no? Si fuera así, entonces, ¿cómo corrijo mi código para que se cree de manera correcta el documento?

[image: Código de JS y query en MongoDB]

Comment: puedes publicar directamente la imagen en tu pregunta, no es necesario el encale :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, porque son objetos y no arrays, por lo tanto la referencia se hace a traves del key, por lo tanto el orden es irrelevante.